# ACF subfield in get_posts

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm looking to query ACF `subfield`s from a group within a group.

Here's my (stripped) code to show where I'm trying to target:

```
acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'events_infos',
    'fields' => array(
        'key' => 'general_infos',
        'type' => 'group',
        'sub_fields' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'dates',
                'sub_fields' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'start', // This is my sort key
                        ...
                    )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

I want to query the upcoming events chronologically so I would need to access; how would I format my `key` in the following `meta_query`?

```
get_posts(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => **events_infos[general_infos][dates][start]**,
            'order' => 'ASC'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: It is in the documentaion under point `4. Sub custom field values` https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Comment: @Stender Thanks a million for your help. I've answered the question and given you the credit for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by [@Stender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244684/stender) [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744435/acf-subfield-in-get-posts?noredirect=1#comment100058641_56744435), the answer can be found i[n the documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/#examples) under the heading **`4. Sub custom field values"`**.